# Move only a specific group of pictures from Android Gallery to PC

Tags: backup, file-transfer, data-transfer

We have an android phone with hundreds of pictures taken from a recent vacation. Because we want to keep those but don't needed them everyday, I'd like to move those images to a desktop computer and leave the phone only with pictures not from the trip.

So the situation is, we have hundreds of pictures spread around multiple albums (pictures taken with the camera plus others received from other people during trip through Whatsapp and other IMs) in Gallery that needs to be transfered to a PC.

I'd like to avoid using share via bluetooth as it's painfully slow and transfer often failed, and be as manufacturer-agnostic as possible. I have searched for solutions, but they were more about backing up the whole thing instead of a part, and we have too many images to manually check.

Ideally there should be a way to select the images across multiple directories that were created between certain dates in an android device and move them to a location in particular. What are my options from here? Shell commands on ADB?

Answer (score 0):

More information is needed such as what type of computer are you using..

Sounds like the easiest way to do this is simply plug your phone in via usb to access the phone's storage and then find the camera and other apps' photo storage folders. From there you should be able to sort by date just like in a normal folder.

You don't need to use the shell. you may need to install google's usb driver though..